# Установка background и сохранение в SharedPreferences в пункте меню

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Приветствую.

У меня в пункте меню есть `checkbox`;

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_check"
    android:title="@string/read_mode"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="true"
    android:checkable="true"/>
```

Который я при создании меню передаю в `SharedPreferences` со значением `false`;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_heads, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("checkbox", false);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_check);
    item.setChecked(isChecked);
    return true;
}
```

Далее, в пункте меню обработчика я кликом меняю значение и сохраняю последнее выбранное;

```
if (id == R.id.action_check) {
        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }
```

Мне нужно чтобы когда у `checkbox` установлена галочка, чтобы мой `layout` загружал один цвет, а когда галочка не установлена то другой. Я получил ссылку на `layout` и одним кликом по `checkbox` устанавливаю цвет, но вторым кликом когда галочка снята ничего не происходит, и вдобавок я не могу полученное значение цвет `background` сохранить в `SharedPreferences`. Как правильно совместить, и сохранить значение?